# How to add custom http headers when using kubectl tool

Tags: kubernetes, http-headers, kubectl

Can not find any issues.

I have to add several custom http headers to access my dedicate api-server proxy, but no clues available right now. Did I miss something?

Comment: @NikitaZernov Accessing Kubernetes API server is more specific. The thing is we have multiple Kubernetes clusters in multiple VPCs, and we can access the apiserver through a central proxy server only. I have to add some cluster infos to find the specific cluster I need when using kubectl. The whole thing may not make any sense, but I have to deal with it by all means.

Comment: Could you add more information, because your explanation is too broad?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Sure. As is above, I need to access multiple clusters' API server through one proxy server. So I have to add some HTTP headers like 'clusterId: xxx' to indicate which one to access.

Comment: You most probably can't.

Comment: You can just add more hosts in proxy config, e.x. https://k8s.example.com/cluster1 -> apiserver cluster 1 IP, https://k8s.example.com/cluster2 -> apiserver cluster 2 IP and so on. Then create kubeconfig for each cluster. That’s how I’ve done it. But in this case you will need to regenerate your apiserver ssl certificate on each cluster. If you choose this way, I can show how to correctly regenerate certificates.

Comment: @NikitaZernov I cannot touch the proxy strategy at all because it's under another team's domain. But I'm curious about why I need to regenerate ssl certificates :D

Comment: Because, as in the example, domain name k8s.example.com must be as an alternative CN for certificate.

Comment: I have another use case here. I need to add some custom headers to access Cloudflare Access endpoints without asking for any password.

Answer (score 3):

This is a dirty hard coded hack to show you how to get the outcome your looking for it's not a fully vetted solution.  This method will compile a new version of kubectl that will add your needed headers.  Maybe it will at least give you a idea to run with.

The reason I wanted to do this is because I put my k8s api endpoint on the internet and safeguarded it with Cloudflare Access. To allow Cloudflare access to let me get past the steel wall I needed to pass in two headers one for my client id and the other for client secret. This ended up working like a charm and is one case someone may want to add custom headers.

**Steps:**

- I assume you have Go installed and setup, if not go do that now.
- git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.git (could take awhile it's pretty big)
- cd kubernetes/staging/src/k8s.io/client-go/transport/
- Open file round_trippers.go in your favorite code editor
- Search for `func (rt userAgentRoundTripper) RoundTrip(req http.Request) (*http.Response, error)`
- Add your needed headers by adding lines like this `req.Header.Set("Bob-Is", "cool")`
- cd back to root folder kubernetes/
- cd cmd/kubectl/
- go build custom-kubectl
- now test it with ./custom-kubectl get ns --v=9
- in that output look for the header you added to the rest calls to K8s api, you should see `-H "Bob-Is: cool"` in the output
- To make this not a hack maybe see if there's a way to add a kubectl plugin you create do to this for you or ask the kind folks in the k8s community how you can make this hacky method a bit cleaner or if there's a reason adding customer headers isn't a good idea.  Worst case parameterize your custom kubectl build to pull in a new parameter you add --custom-request-headers and make it a bit more clean.